# SELECT SUM() with conditions in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have

```
SELECT `Type`, `Originating Country Code`,`Originating Currency Code`, SUM(`Principal Amount`) as Total 
FROM `colab` 
WHERE (`Destination Country Code`='PH' 
    AND `Destination Currency Code`='PHP'
    AND `Type` = 'PAID') || (`Destination Country Code`='PH' 
    AND `Destination Currency Code`='USD'
    AND `Type`= 'PAID')
    GROUP BY `Type`
```

that working fine and returns true please see below

```
country_code | Currency_Code  |   Type    |  Principal

=======================================================
| PH         |   PHP          |    PAID   |    200
=======================================================
```

My Problem is I want to seperate the total principal amount of Currency with USD values. Please see the records inside my database

```
country_code | Currency_Code  |   Type    |  Principal

=======================================================
| PH         |   PHP          |    PAID   |    100
| PH         |   USD          |    PAID   |    100
=======================================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT `Currency_Code`, SUM(`Principal Amount`) as Total 
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `Currency_Code`
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Dream eater, Any idea how can i make another condition?

Comment: @phphopzter Can you be more descriptive about the conditions? Like you want the `type` field to be `W` or your `country_code` to be `PH` or something like that?

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I just want to insert another WHERE clause? but i think it cant be in my query right?? thats why im looking for mySQL query functions to hold 1 or more conditions. thanks

Comment: @phphopzter A single `WHERE` clause can handle multiple conditions with various combinations of `AND` and `OR` syntax. Read more about them [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html) on MySQL dev site.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `GROUP BY` like so:

```
SELECT `Currency_Code`, SUM(`Principal Amount`) as Total 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `Country Code`='PH'
    AND `Type` LIKE '%W%'
GROUP BY `Currency_Code`
```

If you want to add more conditions, just add more parts to the `WHERE` clause using `AND` or `OR` eg:

```
SELECT `Currency_Code`, SUM(`Principal Amount`) as Total 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `Country Code`='PH'
    AND `Type` LIKE '%W%'
    AND `Currency_Code` IN('USD', 'CAD', 'YEN')
    AND `Principal_Amount` > 10
GROUP BY `Currency_Code`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY`

i.e.

```
SELECT `Currency Code`, SUM(`Principal Amount`) as Total 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `Country Code`='PH' 
    AND `Type` LIKE '%W%'
GROUP BY `Currency Code`
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just change the query based on your requirement??
I mean from your expected Result i am inferring that you need the results based on Type or country_code so removing the "AND `Currency Code`='PHP'" from the query will give you the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

Break out your criteria into a subquery and join against it.  Just add as many rules as you'd like.

```
SELECT `Country Code`, `Currency Code`, `Type`,
       SUM(`Principal Amount`) as Total 
FROM `table` 
JOIN (
    SELECT 'PH' as a, 'PHP' as b, '%W%' as c
    UNION SELECT 'PH', 'USD', '%W%'
    UNION SELECT 'PY', 'PYC', '%H%'
) AS criteria
    ON (`table`.`Country Code` = criteria.a and
        `table`.`Currency Code` = criteria.b and
        `table`.`Type` like criteria.c)
GROUP BY `Country Code`, `Currency Code`, `Type`
```