# PHP SQL SUM column with condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `table_order` like below :

```
orderid | orderdate   | price  | deptnr
--------+-------------+--------+----------
1       | 2019-07-12  | 50000  | 1
2       | 2019-07-12  | 30000  | 1
3       | 2019-07-13  | 40000  | 1
4       | 2019-07-14  | 50000  | 1
```

I need to output all column on `table_order` with condition if there are same date, the `price` value will accumulate into one record (record on column 1 and 2 must be merge with total price `50000+30000`). Here what i've  done:

```
// $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table_order
//  WHERE deptnr='$departmetnnr' AND orderstatus='CLOSE'
//  AND orderdate BETWEEN '$oneyearbefore' AND '$currentdate' ORDER BY orderdate"); 

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT SUM(price) AS totalprice 
      FROM table_order 
     WHERE deptnr = '$departmetnnr' 
       AND orderstatus='CLOSE' 
       AND orderdate BETWEEN '$oneyearbefore' AND '$currentdate' 
     ORDER
        BY orderdate
");

$data = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $data[] = ($row);
}               
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Honestly I'm new in PHP and SQL, I try to build simple web service for Mobile Apps, so  I want to process all calculation in server and output as JSON.

I have read some basic statement about PHP and SQL (in w3school, sometime in Stack Overflow answer), problem regarding with mine like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318481/select-sum-with-conditions-in-mysql), but I not yet find the right output. I love to read any suggestion / reference link if available. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY orderdate` if you want to get the sum for each date. This creates one group for each of the distinct values of `orderdate`, and you can then use the aggregate function `SUM()` to get each sum for each group (so for you, that's the sum of price for each date).

If you do not supply a `GROUP BY orderdate`, you just get the sum across all rows.

```sql
SELECT SUM(price) as totalprice, orderdate
FROM table_order
WHERE deptnr='$departmetnnr' 
  AND orderstatus='CLOSE' 
  AND orderdate  BETWEEN '$oneyearbefore' AND '$currentdate' 
GROUP BY orderdate
ORDER BY orderdate
```

That said, you are currently injecting variables directly into the query, which should be avoided by using a prepared statement.

```php
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(price) as totalprice, orderdate
                       FROM table_order
                       WHERE deptnr=? 
                         AND orderstatus='CLOSE' 
                         AND orderdate  BETWEEN ? AND ? 
                       GROUP BY orderdate
                       ORDER BY orderdate");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $departmetnnr, $oneyearbefore, $currentdate);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($totalprice, $orderdate);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $data[] = ["totalprice" => $totalprice, "orderdate" => $orderdate];
}
$stmt->close();
$json = json_encode($data);
```

You can also use SQL functions to create 1 year in the past and get the current date, instead of using PHP values. Use `CURDATE()` to get the current date, then define an interval of 1 year which you subtract from, these will then become the ranges for your `BETWEEN`.

```php
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(price) as totalprice, orderdate
                       FROM table_order
                       WHERE deptnr=? 
                         AND orderstatus='CLOSE' 
                         AND orderdate  BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
                       GROUP BY orderdate
                       ORDER BY orderdate");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $departmetnnr);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($totalprice, $orderdate);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $data[] = ["totalprice" => $totalprice, "orderdate" => $orderdate];
}
$stmt->close();
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Why using prepare?? by the way your explanation very very clear, but still get some error in line with `bind_param`

Comment: And which error is that? And you should ***always*** use `prepare()` when you need PHP variables in the query. Always! It's to prevent SQL injection at worst, and prevent the data from breaking your query at best.

Comment: oh usually I put directly the variable into sql statement, because the variable have HTTP header value, I try to modify with prepare then. The error is `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in`

Comment: Don't use variables in the query - use placeholders and use `prepare()`, especially those that come from any sort of user-input. -- I don't see `deptnr` in the table-definition you had above. Is that part of the `table_order` table? `$stmt` will be a boolean if the query fails (which would happen regardless if you use `prepare()` or `query()` -- don't use `query()` here.. ;-)

Comment: You can add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`  before creating your connection `new mysqli()`/`mysqli_connect()` to get more specific errors.

Comment: ah yaa I'm sorry, `deptnr` is part of column on table_order, I'll edit the question

Comment: As stated above, add the line with `mysqli_report()` before your connection and you will get an exception with *why* the query failed.

Comment: Thank you for  all advice, its solve now with little modification :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `GROUP BY orderdate` and you are good to go.